# asking for permission from the user to autodetect SIM phone number - xCode

Tags: iphone, ios, phone-number

There's a forbidden function by apple for getting a user's phone number because this may be intrusive and so on.

this is the code as far as I know

```
NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
```

I was wondering... what about before doing that the app should be displaying in a UIAlertView the approval of the user for such action, is that a valid solution???

thanks in advance folks!

Comment: What does Xcode have to do with that at all?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE. Thanks!

Comment: aww rockie mistake, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with undocumented functions is that they can't be relied upon. Any version update could break them. That said, the bigger issue is if Apple will approve an app that uses such a call. If not (consensus seems to be that they are not in favor of using SBFormattedPhoneNumber) then simply asking the user for permission before doing it will probably not buy you any points in the approval process. My suggestion would be to avoid this and simply ask the user for their phone number if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be rejected by the review team if it uses *any* forbidden API at all. Alert view or no alert view.

Answer (score 1):

`SBFormattedPhoneNumber` is not present anymore after `ios4` version. Basically there is no way to do it. Trying to access the number by some undocumented way would risk your app getting rejected.

Here is Apple response about this functionality

> "For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security feature known as the application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on."
>
> The device's phone number is not available within your application's container. You will need to revise your application to read only within your directory container and resubmit your binary to iTunes Connect in order for your application to be reconsidered for the App Store.